# How to embed a UILabel inside a UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to create a UIView programmaticaly in swift, that view should contain an image and a label. Also I need to embed that label and the imageview inside that created view so that as I animate the constraints of the view, the label and the image shold also reposition itseld relative to the view. This is my code co far -

```
func banner(viewController:UIViewController){
   let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
   let dynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: -70, width:width, height:70))
   let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 35, width:width, height:20))
   dynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
   label.center = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 35)
   label.textAlignment = .center
   label.text = "I'am a test label"
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
     dynamicView.frame = dynamicView.frame.offsetBy( dx: 0, dy: 70 )
     viewController.view.addSubview(DynamicView)
     viewController.view.addSubview(label)
   }

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 3, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 4, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: { 
     dynamicView.frame = DynamicView.frame.offsetBy( dx: 0, dy: -70 )
     }, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

I could achieve that by changing x and y position of each views,labels etc separately. But that code would not be clean and consise.

Comment: Try adding label as subview to your Dynamic view like
DynamicView.addSubview(label)

Comment: @Romit Kumar as you are new to swift its ok to start working with frames, but now it's recommended to use constraints for adding views programmatically.

Comment: @RomitKumar is it working ?

Comment: @Romit Kumar and variable name should start with lower case letter ex-: dynamicView.

Comment: edited @TusharSharma

Comment: @Romit kumar's re Tushar Sharma's comment. Working with both frames and constraints can get a little hairy. If you lay these views out with frames and not constraints, but later try and animate them by applying constraints (as your question suggests) it will likely be problematic. Normally do all frames or all autolayout (aka constraints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question, it is seen that you are adding the label as subview to the viewController's view. Since you wish to embed the label to the Dynamic view try adding the label to Dynamic view like

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
     dynamicView.frame = dynamicView.frame.offsetBy( dx: 0, dy: 70 )
     viewController.view.addSubview(DynamicView)
     dynamicView.addSubview(label)
   }
```